# Command Pattern In C++

Tags: c++, pointers, design-patterns, command

So I'm trying to learn the Command Pattern for C++ and I am unsure on how to Bind my commands.
My current code has my Input Handler and Commands, but I don't know how to bind them. I keep getting
a "error: 'Command' is an inaccessible base of 'UpCommand'".

InputHandler.h

```
#ifndef INPUTHANDLER_H_INCLUDED
#define INPUTHANDLER_H_INCLUDED
#include "Command.h"

class InputHandler
{
public:
    void handleInput();

    //Bind Buttons Here

private:
    Command* buttonW;
    Command* buttonA;
    Command* buttonS;
    Command* buttonD;
};

#endif // INPUTHANDLER_H_INCLUDED
```

And here is my Command.h

Command.h

```
#ifndef COMMAND_H_INCLUDED
#define COMMAND_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>

class Command
{
public:
    virtual ~Command() {}
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};

class UpCommand : Command
{
    virtual void execute() {std::cout << "UP";}
};

class DownCommand : Command
{
    virtual void execute() {std::cout << "DOWN";}
};

class LeftCommand : Command
{
    virtual void execute() {std::cout << "LEFT";}
};

class RightCommand : Command
{
    virtual void execute() {std::cout << "RIGHT";}
};

#endif // COMMAND_H_INCLUDED
```

I can't figure out how to bind my pointers in InputHandler to the subCommands for direction. Can anyone explain to me how it's done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use public inheritance instead of private.  Either change `class` to `struct` everywhere or say `class WTFCommand : public Command`.

This is what the error, "base class inaccessible," means.